# Can't build after adding Notebook Control in Glest

Tags: python, python-2.7, glade, canonical-quickly

After watching this video:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/

I've created an Ubuntu application using Quickly and Glade. However, after adding a tab control (called a Notebook in glade), I hit the save button in Glade.

When I try to run my application (by typing "quickly run") at the command prompt, I get his error:

```
Gtk:ERROR:/build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.6.4/./gtk/gtknotebook.c:1235:gtk_notebook_buildable_add_child: assertion failed: (page != NULL)
```

If I delete that same notebook control in Glade, save, and run. I get no error.

I'm not sure what to do next. Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843311/why-is-the-notebook-control-not-showing-up-in-my-window).

You must put another control into the notebook control before it will build at all.